# Delphi - Set form to not focus on any component when it shows

Tags: delphi

Is there a way in Delphi to disallow the form to focus on any of its components but not disabling those components? I tried `Self.SetFocus` on `FormActivate` event of the form but the program says that it cannot focus on a disabled component.

Comment: Minor notice: I do not think that the *compiler* says so, but the program produced by the compiler.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the following `OnActivate` event handler:

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ActiveControl:= nil;
end;
```